# No vertical white space after References title in Bibliography

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, natbib

For some reason, there is no blank space between the bibliography section title (References) and the first reference. I am currently using `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` as bibliography style and document class `article` (`\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}`). Does anyone have an idea how to get a baseline skip in between the title 'References' and the first reference?

EDIT: I am using `\usepackage{natbib}`.

EDIT2: My preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[hang,normalsize,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{bbm}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
%\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\gargantuaan}{\fontsize{7}{8}\selectfont}

%\hypersetup{
%  colorlinks=false,% hyperlinks will be black
%  linkbordercolor=white,% hyperlink borders will be red
%  pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0}% border style will be underline of width 1pt
%}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.8em}}
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.8em}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
```

Comment: With the limited information you are providing, I can only recommend using `\vspace*{3mm}` where '3mm' can be set as much space as you want.

Comment: Without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe) it is very difficult to predict the behaviour of some not-working code, please provide one if you can.

Comment: I understand. There is just not too much I can give as an MWE. Perhaps this helps: http://s24.postimg.org/aigpfgf05/Example.png You can see there is no space between 'References' and the first reference. Further, the title References is at the right location. As for tex coding, I use the following to create the bibliography: 

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

Comment: Does this behavior persist if you create a minimal test document like `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{natbib}\begin{document}\nocite{*}\bibliographystyle{apalike}\bibliography{bib_name_here}\end{document}`? If it does **not** persist, then you should be able to go through the process of creating an MWE that you can then post so we can help you further.

Comment: Thanks for that Adam. So I did the minimal test document and the problem did **not** persist. Here is my preamble (part 1):

`\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{a4wide}`

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting, could you direct me to an explanation on how to create a better MWE?

Many thanks!

Comment: I updated the original question with my preamble, are there perhaps any packages that might cause the issue?

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). You can also use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863). And here's a link explaining what a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is, though I think @AndreaL. linked to this above.

Comment: Also, you can use `@` before someone's name in a comment [to have that person receive a notification](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598/when-writing-a-comment-how-do-i-ensure-that-the-person-it-is-addressed-to-gets) that you have directed a comment at them.

Comment: The problem is not related to the code in the preamble...

Comment: I cannot actually reproduce your problem with that MWE. I would suggest: (i) [making sure your TeX distribution is up to date](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution); and (ii) trying to go through the process of creating an actual MWE, where you create the most **minimal** document possible that actually reproduces the problem when you compile it. As @karlkoeller just pointed out, it seems that the problem isn't related to the preamble.

Comment: I'm so sorry but the problem was really stupid. For the appendices prior to the bibliography, I had inserted
`\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*-3}{*-0.1}`
which caused the issue. I had forgotten about this as I put it in a long time ago and not seen the references (title) for a while.

Thanks so much for your time anyway!

Comment: Hmm, I now just wonder how to put it back to default. When I use `\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*3}{*0.1}` after the Appendices, it still has the first reference directly below the title.

Comment: {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}

got it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a mistake made and solved by the OP.